# Using multiple parameters as filter in angular2 route in same component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use angular2 routes as a filter on my app.

I want that, all the route pointing to "sc", use the `HomeComponent`" but with different filter.

I want to do something like this:

```
/sc/:category1/:category2
```

example:

```
/sc/scifi  = `HomeComponent` with `:category1` = 'scifi'
```

example 2 :

```
/sc/scifi/movies = `HomeComponent` with `:category1` = 'scifi' and `:category2` = 'movies'
```

I've tried a lot of different way but was not able to do it. I'm using the last release of angular2 ( `"@angular/router": "~3.0.2"`  and  `"@angular/common": "~2.0.2"`

I've tried that:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'sc', redirectTo: 'sc/', pathMatch: 'full'  },
            { path: 'sc/:category1', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'sc/:category1/:category2', component: HomeComponent },
        ]
```

And I've tried that:

```
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'sc/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'sc', redirectTo: 'sc/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
       path: 'sc/:subCalendarName',
       component: HomeComponent,
       children: [
              { path: '' },
              { path: ':subCalendarName' },
              { path: ':subCalendarName/:category' }
       ]
    },
```

Here is my plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JHEg3RRzRXNVNK83jSsL?p=preview

Comment: Any error message? What is the actual behavior? A Plunker would be helpful.

Comment: I'll try to make a plunker with it but I was hoping for "maybe I missed something about a way to do multiple nested parameters".

Comment: `{ path: 'sc', redirectTo: 'sc/', pathMatch: 'full'  },` is invalid. You need to pass a parameter or create a route that doesn't expect a parameter. You don't need the trailing `/` but I don't know if it can cause troubles. `{ path: '' },` should have `pathMatch: 'full'`.

Comment: I've added a plunker

Comment: You can't have a route without a component, redirect or children ` { path: '' },`. You can add a dummy component that doesn't display anything.

Comment: ok excellent. I've added the dummyComponent, but still, I'm not able to get my `:category2` parameter.. I've updated the plunker ( https://plnkr.co/edit/JHEg3RRzRXNVNK83jSsL?p=preview)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want https://plnkr.co/edit/3MtcwrijvcCQWxKOD4qs?p=preview.

Comment: Well it does work in this context but I would really prefer that those 2 routes ( `/sc/:category1` and `sc/:category1/:category2`) were loaded as children. So it will not reinitiate all the `HomeComponent` but just the  `<router-outlet ></router-outlet>` in the `HomeComponent`

Comment: Ok, at least I know now better what you want. I'll have another look later.